# HSL to RGB Auto-Color with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, d3.js, ng-class

I have a few different working pieces here, but I'm struggling with how to to bring them all together. I currently have a list of elements sorted by their health status (value given between 0 and 100).

For each element, I would like to color the background based on its health status. So, status = 0 would mean I have a fill color of red; status=50 yellow; status=100 green.

In something like d3, I would accomplish that with the following code (which, is a great trick, by the way):

```
    /*normalize input between 0 and 100 to hsl color scale -- so 0=0 and 100 = 120, where  hue=0 is red and hue=120 is green */    

var hueScale = d3.scale.linear().domain([0,100]).range([0,120]); 

    .style("fill", function(d){
        var hslColor = 'hsl(' + hueScale(d.status)) + ', ' + (100) + '%, ' + (50) + '%, ' + (1) + ')'; 
        return d3.rgb(hslColor).toString().toUpperCase(); })
```

but here, I'm dealing with a normal list, not a d3 graphic.

I've also made use of ng-class in the past to specify a dynamic color:

```
$scope.getClass = function(status) {
    if (status == (100)) {
        return "good-feed"; 
    } else {
        return "bad-feed";
    }
    };
```

and

```
   ng-class="[getClass(item.status)]"
```

I need to combine both of these techniques. I think using ng-class in a similar way to what I have is what I need to do, but I'm not sure how to get the color change function to work without being needlessly complicated.

Any thoughts?

**EDIT** 
Both my current code snippets above work, but the issue is I want to be able to iterate through all status values between 0 and 100, not just handle an either-or situation.

For example:

- Item 1 with status of 23 (approx. color: orange)
- Item 2 with status of 45 (approx. color: yellow-orange)
- Item 3 with status of 67 (approx. color: yellow-green)
- Item 4 with status of 99 (approx. color: green)

And so on. Now, I COULD write my color function for ng-class to look something like this (update: this doesn't work) :

```
$scope.getClass = function(status) {
    if (status <= (10)) {
        return "dark-red"; 
    } else if (10 < status <= 20){
        return "red-orange"; 
// continue pattern for all intervals until 100 is reached
    } else {
        return "undefined-grey";
    }
};
```

But manually going through like that for each value seems clunky. Is there any way to make this smoother (akin to the d3 solution)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so this answer is the best I've got for now. It still requires some work to get this to do exactly what I would like, but it's on the right track:

I ended up usuing jquery to break apart colors based on value (like I was attempting to do with my ng-class function)

See my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KateJean/ts8wzh6b/) for details.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var cell = $('ul.list-view li');

cell.each(function() {
var cell_value = parseFloat($(this).html().slice(0, -1));

// Positief

if ((cell_value >= 0) && (cell_value <= 0.3)) {
    $(this).css({'background-color' : '#7FFF95'});   
} 
else if ((cell_value >= 0.31) && (cell_value <= 0.5)) {
    $(this).css({'background-color' : '#66FF7C'});
} 
else if ((cell_value >= 0.51) && (cell_value <= 0.7)) {
    $(this).css({'background-color' : '#4DFF63'});
} 
else if ((cell_value >= 0.71) && (cell_value <= 1)) {
    $(this).css({'background-color' : '#33F749'});
}
else if ((cell_value >= 1.01) && (cell_value <= 1.5)) {
    $(this).css({'background-color' : '#1ADE30'});
}
else if (cell_value >= 1.5) {
    $(this).css({'background-color' : '#00CC66'});
}

// Negatief

else if ((cell_value >= -0.01) && (cell_value <= -0.2)) {
    $(this).css({'background-color' : '#F6ADAC'});
}
else if ((cell_value >= -0.31) && (cell_value <= -0.5)) {
    $(this).css({'background-color' : '#F18483'});
}
else if ((cell_value >= 0.51) && (cell_value <= -0.7)) {
    $(this).css({'background-color' : '#EF706E'});
}
else if ((cell_value >= -0.71) && (cell_value <= -1)) {
    $(this).css({'background-color' : '#ED5B5A'});
}
else if ((cell_value >= -1.01) && (cell_value <= -1.5)) {
    $(this).css({'background-color' : '#EB4745'});
}
else if (cell_value >= -1.5) {
$(this).css({'background-color' : '#E93331'});
}

});
```

Answer (score 0):

just use this

```
ng-class="{'good-feed' : item.status == 100,'bad-feed' : item.status != 100 }"
```

Comment: right -- that definitely works in the case where there's an "either-or" situation. I'll make sure to update my question to be clearer. That is not what I am going for. 

 Both my current code snippets above work (and in fact, my solution above gives the same result as yours) , but the issue is I want to be able to iterate through all status values between 0 and 100, not just handle an either-or situation. 

For example: 
Item1, status = 23 (color: orange) 
Item2, status = 45 (color: yellow-orange) 
Item3, status = 67 (color: yellow-green) 
Item4, status = 99 (color: green)